# Как исправить запись в файле локализации?

Tags: html, wordpress, локализация

У меня мультиязычный сайт на WordPress, хочу исправить и укоротить запись в локализации.

В файле .pot была такая запись

```
#: 404.php:26
msgid ""
"It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the links "
"below or a search?"
msgstr ""
```

которая переводила эту строчку

```
<p><?php _e( 'It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?', 'onepress' ); ?></p>
```

Я удалил второе предложение и стало вот так:

```
#: 404.php:26
msgid ""
"It looks like nothing was found at this location."
msgstr ""
```

и пытаюсь добиться его перевода вот так:

```
<p><?php _e( 'It looks like nothing was found at this location.', 'onepress' ); ?></p>
```

В самом файле перевода .po сделал обновление из .pot файла и перевел строку на русский, но теперь уже не переводит и выводит только английский вариант.. Что я делаю не так?

Все изменения вносил через notepad++ и poedit.

Comment: речь про https://wordpress.org/themes/onepress/ ?

Comment: И не нужно трогать оригинальны строки лангпака. Они всё равно  затрутся при обновлении. В чем проблема? Перевести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 'twentyfifteen' не просто так там стоит, а указывает на текстовый домен трансляции, который должен быть подгружен через load_theme_textdomain() и существовать в виде файла /wp-content/languages/themes/twentyfifteen-ru_RU.mo или в папке темы /wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/languages/ru_RU.mo.

Вы заменили этот аргумент на onepress - поэтому ничего и не работает.

Comment: спасибо, но это по моем невнимательности переноса сюда. и там и там `onepress`

Comment: А файл компилировали из .po в .mo? И новый .mo на сайт залили?

Comment: На сайт все залил. Что вы имеете ввиду под компиляцией? В файле `.po` через poedit настраивал перевод и нажимал сохранить. Или нужно что-то дополнительно еще делать?

Comment: Когда вы сохраняете файл .po в poedit, то редактор автоматически создает новый .mo в той же папке. Это скомпилированный файл. Именно его читает система переводов, ни .po, ни .pot ее не волнуют. Надо новый, скомпилированный .mo заливать на сайт.

Comment: удалил, скомпилировал новый - тот же результат..
но почему вот эта строка работает
`_e( 'Oops! That page can&rsquo;t be found.', 'onepress' );`

Comment: Трудно сказать. У вас на вид все правильно. Какая-то неточность в чем-то.

Comment: уфф, разобрался!.. .pot файл лежал в папке темы (куда я и скидывал файлы .po и .mo) `onepress/languages/`, а считывало перевод с папки
`wp-content/languages` Спасибо за помощь!